Null reference at iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfString.DecodeContent() error after adding pdfoutline and on document close method
        pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(output, writeProperties); 
        PdfOutline root = destDoc.GetOutlines(false);
        PdfOutline helloWorld = root.AddOutline("Hello World");
        destDoc.Close();  

After adding pdfoutline and closing document throws error

at iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfString.DecodeContent()
at iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfString.GenerateValue()
at iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfString.GetValueBytes()
at iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfString.GenerateContent()
at iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfWriter.WriteToBody(PdfObject pdfObj)
at iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument.FlushInfoDictionary(Boolean appendMode)
at iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument.Close()
